# Sympy Not Symbolically Solving Equation at Solveset Call

Tags: python, sympy

Using Python 3.9.7 in VS code. I'm doing some stress analysis in python:

```
from math import sin, cos, tan, degrees, radians
from operator import eq
from sympy import *

x, y, z, a = symbols("x y z a")
vm_crit =  ((x - y)**2 + (y - z)**2 + (z - x)**2)**(1/2) -(2**(1/2))*a
vm_crit_sub = vm_crit.subs(x, z)
vm_crit_solve = solveset(vm_crit_sub,y)

print(vm_crit_solve)
```

I get:

```
ConditionSet(y, Eq(-1.4142135623731*a + ((-y + z)**2 + (y - z)**2)**0.5, 0), Complexes)
```

The second argument is correct, but for some reason the function isn't solving for 'y'. If I get rid of the squares:

```
x, y, z, a = symbols("x y z a")
vm_crit =  (x + y + z) - a
vm_crit_sub = vm_crit.subs(x, z)
vm_crit_solve = solveset(vm_crit_sub,y)

print(vm_crit_solve)
```

I get:

```
{a - 2*z}
```

This is correct.

In sympy do you have to expand before solving? If so, is there a way around it?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: In general, it is a bad idea to `import from math` when you are working with sympy, as those libraries don't mix well. (As `math` isn't used in this code sample, that is only a potential problem when you'd extend the code.) The real problem here is that sympy gets confused with floats, as they are imprecise and sympy looks for exact symbolic solutions.  Python immediately converts `1/2` to the float `0.5`. You can circumvent that conversion by writing `1/2` as a rational or as `S(1)/2` (or by using `sqrt` here). Then the result is `{-a + z, a + z}`.

Comment: Thank you. The first item in the result is correct, but there shouldn't be a second item since the problem reduces nicely down to    y = z - a. Any idea how to eliminate the second item?

Comment: Well, `sqrt((y-z)**2)` is not necessarily equal to `y-z`, as it could be negative or even complex. Both solutions seem to correctly fit the equation.

Comment: Is there a way to tell Sympy that z - y > 0? The will reduce the solution down to y = z - a.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, Sympy isn't very apt (yet?) in working with that type of conditions.